# change how webview goes back when html5 video is in full screen

Tags: android, html5-video

I have an app that loads a newspaper website. The user can visit a news and watch a video if there is one. If the video is in full screen when he/she presses the back button the app goes to the newsspaper home page instead of the news.

Activity code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if (QuickstartPreferences.getIfIsInFullScreen(this)) {
        Log.i("myApp", "is in fullScreen");
    }
    ...
    if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    }
}
```

QuickstartPreferences code:

```
public static boolean getIfIsInFullScreen(Activity myActivityReference) {
    boolean fullScreen = (myActivityReference.getWindow().getAttributes().flags & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN) != 0;
    return fullScreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

override onBackPressed in your activity then check like this

```
if (webView.canGoBack()){
    // your bussiness logic goes here
      } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
         }
```

Comment: I'm using `canGoBack()` in `onKeyDown()`with `myWebView.goBack()`